# Treeview with data type dependent header and items

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a TreeView structure of:

```
> {Name} {ParentButton}
 > ParentData.Text
 > {Name} {ChildButton}
  > ChildData.Text
  > {Name} {ChildButton}
   > ...
> {Name} {ParentButton}
 > ParentData.Text
 > ...
```

I've come up with the following:

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:ParentModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding ParentData.Name}"></Label>
        <Button Content="MyParentButton" Command="{Binding ParentButton}"></Button>
      </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:ChildModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding ChildData.Name}"></Label>
        <Button Content="MyChildButton" Command="{Binding ChildButton}"></Button>
      </StackPanel>
    </HierarhicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

ParentModel.cs

```cs
public class ParentModel {
  public ParentOnlyObj ParentData { get; }
  public ICommand ParentButton { get; }
  public ObservableCollection<ChildModel> Children { get; }
}
```

ChildModel.cs

```cs
public class ChildModel {
  public ChildOnlyObj ChildData { get; }
  public ICommand ChildButton { get; }
  public ObservableCollection<ChildModel> Children { get; }
}
```

With my attempt, I am getting:

```
> {Name} {ParentButton}
 > ParentData.Text (?? how to add)
 > {Name} {ChildButton}
  > ChildData.Text (?? how to add)
> {Name} {ParentButton}
 > ParentData.Text (?? how to add)
```

If the `Models` contains two `ParentModel` where the first contains one child.

That makes sense since I have not specified where `Text` is in the XAML. It's just that I'm confused on how to do that.

I am trying to have a `TreeView` items based on two models, but those two models must change the item's header as well as content, where the content may include further `ChildModel`.

Comment: Could you please clarify what your issue is? What does "(?? how to add)" mean?

Comment: @mm8 I would like my TreeViewItem's to have Model specific data in it, but I do not know how to do that with Model specific TreeViewItem headers as well.

Comment: Put the model specific data in the `DataTemplate` for each model?

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: What model specific data are you trying to display?

Comment: ChildData or ParentData in ChildModel and ParentModels.

Comment: So how do you for example want to display an `ParentOnlyObj`?

Comment: It should be the content of a ParentModel TreeViewItem, like displaying it's `.Text`. After that, if ParentModel has any Children, you will be able to expand its children, and then from then on, it'll be ChildModels.

ChildModels have a ChildOnlyObj, and along the same lines, a child content should be its `.Text` and another item with Children again.